# Child elements in XAML

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-runtime

I'm just learning XAML so bear with me.

When you nest an element in XAML it seems like that element is set to the "Child" property of the parent UI.

However in the following code the child element is set to the value. That sort of makes sense - kinda.

However then Border Element below was set to the ControlTemplate, yet ControlTemplate has no Child element, so can someone tell me what exactly is the relationship between the Border and ControlTemplate below? May be you could re-write this snippet in c# as an explanation.

```
 <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="dtp:PickerSelectorItem">

                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Picker">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
               <!-- There is more code but snipped for irrelevance-->
```

Also how does the XAML compiler makes sense of what the child element actually does? Ie, how does it know that the child element should be set to the "Child" property, whereas other times it'd be set to the "Value" property as seen above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The XAML parser uses the [`ContentPropertyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute.aspx) to determine how to handle child xaml elements. For example, if you look at the following two base controls you'll see how their usage is:

[`ContentControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx):

```
[ContentPropertyAttribute("Content")]
public class ContentControl : Control, IAddChild { ... }
```

[`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx):

```
[ContentPropertyAttribute("Items")]
public class ItemsControl : Control, IAddChild, IContainItemStorage { ... }
```

It used to be that you would implement the [`IAddChild`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.iaddchild.aspx) interface, but that is obsolete now. Also, the xaml parsing engine can recognize if your "content" property is pointing to a single object or a collection of objects. Basically, if you want to create your own custom control, make sure to use the correct attribute to control how your child(ren) are handled.

Comment: Just found out about it and was about to update my answer. Nice, +1.

Comment: @m-y I think you got it in this one. Thank you, that really solves a lot of the mysteries XD lol

Comment: **With Silverlight** use [AlternateContentProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.alternatecontentpropertyattribute(v=vs.95).aspx) on content property to see more than one content (Header + Content) in Blend...

Answer (score 2):

The XAML parser knows which property to assign the inner XAML to according to the parent object type. For example, nesting XAML under a `ContentControl` will call `parentContentControl.Content = child`, while for `ItemsControl` it will add the children to the `Items` collection: `parentItemsControl.Items.Add(child)`.

I guess the same is true for `FrameworkTemplate` objects (which `ControlTemplate` derives from), and child controls for these types are assigned to the `VisualTree` property.

Comment: Thanks for your help! but ugh, isn't that confusing? Is there a spec paper that details the parser's behavior.

Comment: There are very little other examples of this in the framework, so knowing these three mostly got you covered. I'm not aware of a paper that talks about this, but it would be interesting to look at `XamlReader`'s source code to find other cases.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, ControlTemplate uses FrameElementFactory to construct the controls defined on XAML and builds the visual tree which is finally assigned to ControlTemplate's VisualTree property.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yeah I think it's assigning to the "VisualTree" property, and not "Template" as accounted by @adilester